# Alternative expressions for "Our university is strong in [medicine, languages, social sciences, etc.]"

Tags: speech, synonyms

This is in the context of a university president verbally promoting the departments in his university which are nationally or internationally competitive.

One way, although I admit it is a bit clunky, to express this idea is the sentence mentioned in the title: "Our university is strong in [medicine, languages, social sciences, etc.]."

What are some alternative sentences with the same meaning, that is, changing the "is strong in" to another verb phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest saying

> Our university **excels** in ...

Comment: Why do you suggest that?

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> Our university is **proficient in** varied fields such as medicine,
>   languages, social sciences, and so on.

In some other context, you could use words like **potent**, **effective**, or **adept**. But they may not suit your context, hence I have suggested **proficient** which seems to fit here.

Comment: Doesn't this usually collocate with a person, not an institution?

Comment: I have seen a few examples with institutions and organizations as well.

Comment: @Matma D: If any of your sources are online, I'd like to see them!

Comment: [Google Books 1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=hUVfeJSs0_MC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22organization+is+proficient+in%22&source=bl&ots=xJhwhZy2vY&sig=o6_IU7qB2McIqrf2hRXmujca374&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAmoVChMI_omQvuKCyQIVR1aOCh26lwIK#v=onepage&q=%22organization%20is%20proficient%20in%22&f=false) & [Google Books 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2Xt8c_ow22wC&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45&dq=%22organization+is+proficient+in%22&source=bl&ots=el6dkq0fGc&sig=EUeXXRt8BQnq2OUT9sv48bc2wPY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBWoVChMI7Kqu_OKCyQIV0JGOCh3SBQHQ#v=onepage&q=%22organization%20is%20proficient%20in%22&f=false)

Comment: Interesting! In this context, [it doesn't look like there are any examples using "university" as the subject.](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22organization+is+proficient+in%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22university+is+proficient+in%22)

Comment: In that case, **excels** in above answer is perfect. You can accept that.